# Help me to find this magazine

Tags: reference-request

Some years ago I've read a mathematical magazine about pigeonhole principle. I love the structure of the magazine, first it explains about the subject and after it has a lot of interesting exercises about the same topic.

Someone knows a mathematical magazine that has this structure?

Comment: Are you sure its not just [brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/wiki/pigeonhole-principle-definition/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend the math newsletter called [Mathematical Excalibur](https://www.math.ust.hk/excalibur/) edited by [Kin-Yin Li](https://www.math.ust.hk/~makyli/) (Department of Mathematics - The Hong Kong University).

It's free and the [first issue](https://www.math.ust.hk/excalibur/v1_n1.pdf) is just about the Pigeonhole Principle. Each issue has a main topic.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm almost sure it is this magazine I was looking for